# Android orientation change prevent to switch layout-land

Tags: android

I have created  layout and layout-land for both portrait and landscape view in android. I want that not refreshing the activity how i switch from layout to layout-land . As i have put `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest that prevent to switch from layout to layout-land.

I want:

1. Activity not refresh when change orientation
2. Switch XML from layout to layout-land or vice versa  when change orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **onSaveInstanceState()** to save data which you need to bind when application config. will change and you can rebind that saved data in **onRestoreInstanceState**() method. here given link will helps you.

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/

Note : you need to remove `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` from menifest file file you want to call onConfigurationChanged()

You can store data in Bundle of activity in onSaveInstanceState() method like

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putLong("param", value);
}
```

And you can retrieve that data in

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  if (icicle != null){
    value = icicle.getLong("param");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how i use onSaveInstanceState() to store data

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't achieve this(only with some hacks). Take a look at Android Activity Lifecycle: android destroys activty when oriantation changes. So you cant switch from portrait to land (and back) without reinstantiating activity.